# How to interpret cogemur

Tags: vocabulary, latin-to-english-translation

I would like to know how to translate *cogemur*. I saw that it is the first-person plural future passive indicative *cogo*. But *cogo* translates as 'force' to me in Google Translate. So that doesn't seem to make much sense as a verb. Being strong?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*Cogo* has various meanings, including "to force" in the sense of "compel, make someone do something"; it can also mean "to gather or collect". A precise translation will depend on the context, but in the first-person plural future passive indicative, *cogemur* might mean "we will be forced / compelled / constrained", or possibly "we will be gathered / collected / mustered". If you have a sentence in which the word occurs, we'll be able to tell you more.

Comment: That's an excellent response! It is actually the acronym of a repository for researchers to share computer generated music, so I think the meaning may be perfect :)